# Coqtop cannot load file

Tags: coq

I'm currently working on Software Foundations – Logical Foundation.

In short, I got error `Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix <> and prefix LF`.

---

I have Coq brew installed.

I have the following files located at `~/Documents/Notes/PL/SF/LF/`

- `_CoqProject` contains single line: `-Q . LF`
- `Basics.v` contains code for the first chapter
- `Makefile` generated by command `coq_makefile -f _CoqProject *.v -o Makefile`

Then I make `Basics.vo` by `make Basics.vo`

---

Now I open `coqtop`, and try to run the command `From LF Require Export Basics.` and here is what it looks like

```
╭─~/Documents/Notes/PL/SF/LF
╰─$ coqtop

Welcome to Coq 8.11.0 (January 2020)

Coq < From LF Require Export Basics.

Toplevel input, characters 23-29:
> From LF Require Export Basics.
>                        ^^^^^^
Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix
<> and prefix LF
```

Here is the output of `Print LoadPath.`. The last line of the output clearly shows `<> /Users/myname/Documents/Notes/PL/SF/LF`, for which I don't know what does it mean.

```
Coq <
Coq < Print LoadPath.
Logical Path / Physical path:
<> /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/share/coq
latex /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/share/coq/latex
<> /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/user-contrib
Ltac2 /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/user-contrib/Ltac2
Coq /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins
Coq.firstorder /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/firstorder
Coq.ltac /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/ltac
Coq.extraction /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/extraction
Coq.btauto /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/btauto
Coq.syntax /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/syntax
Coq.nsatz /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/nsatz
Coq.omega /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/omega
Coq.cc /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/cc
Coq.derive /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/derive
Coq.ssr /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/ssr
Coq.rtauto /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/rtauto
Coq.micromega /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/micromega
Coq.funind /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/funind
Coq.setoid_ring /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/setoid_ring
Coq.ssrmatching /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/plugins/ssrmatching
Coq /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories
Coq.PArith /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/PArith
Coq.MSets /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/MSets
Coq.QArith /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/QArith
Coq.Sorting /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Sorting
Coq.Program /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Program
Coq.ZArith /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/ZArith
Coq.Bool /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Bool
Coq.Sets /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Sets
Coq.NArith /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/NArith
Coq.Wellfounded /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Wellfounded
Coq.Arith /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Arith
Coq.Vectors /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Vectors
Coq.Reals /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Reals
Coq.Logic /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Logic
Coq.Floats /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Floats
Coq.Classes /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Classes
Coq.Lists /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Lists
Coq.Relations /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Relations
Coq.Unicode /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Unicode
Coq.Structures /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Structures
Coq.Setoids /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Setoids
Coq.Numbers.Integer.Binary
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Integer/Binary
Coq.Numbers.Integer.NatPairs
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Integer/NatPairs
Coq.Numbers.Integer.Abstract
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Integer/Abstract
Coq.Numbers.Integer
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Integer
Coq.Numbers.NatInt
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/NatInt
Coq.Numbers.Natural.Binary
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Natural/Binary
Coq.Numbers.Natural.Peano
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Natural/Peano
Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Natural/Abstract
Coq.Numbers.Natural
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Natural
Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.Int63
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Cyclic/Int63
Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.Int31
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Cyclic/Int31
Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.ZModulo
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Cyclic/ZModulo
Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.Abstract
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Cyclic/Abstract
Coq.Numbers.Cyclic
  /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers/Cyclic
Coq.Numbers /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Numbers
Coq.Compat /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Compat
Coq.Strings /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Strings
Coq.Init /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/Init
Coq.FSets /usr/local/Cellar/coq/8.11.0/lib/coq/theories/FSets
<> /Users/myname/Documents/Notes/PL/SF/LF
```

Can anyone help me figure out what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate the current directory (`.../LF`) to the `LF` prefix:

```
(* In coqtop *)
Add LoadPath "." as LF.

(* So that... *)
Print LoadPath.
(* shows:
     ...
     LF /Users/.../LF
*)
```

I also heard that directly using coqtop is strongly discouraged, and instead it is recommended to use a proper editor (VSCode, Emacs + Proof General, CoqIDE).

Comment: Yea actually I didn't use coqtop but vscode + vscoq, which in turn runs coqtop eventually. I didn't mention that in the question to simplify what happened. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use `vscode` and `vscoq` and also face with this problem. It should be mentioned that, if your workspace folder is not directly the `lf/` folder downloaded from the webset, you'd better load full path instead of `.` as `LF`. (In this situation, it seems that the `coqtop` cannot see the `_Coqproject` too.)

A convenient solution is to load full path in the current `.v` file.

```
Add LoadPath "D:\path\to\lf\" as LF.
```

Comment: I don't know why I got downvoted :-(.
Is there somewhere not clear?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted. Opening `lf/` as my workspace folder fixed it for me 